# Generating set of a submodule

Tags: abstract-algebra

Is it true that the generating set for $N=\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{Z}^3 : 2x+3y−5z=0\}$ as a submodule of $\mathbb{Z}^3$ is $\{(1,1,1),(3,-2,0)\}$?

Comment: Are you sure you wanted to write $\mathbb Z^3$ and not $F^3$, where $F$ is some field (e.g. real numbers)? We can't talk about subspaces here, since $\mathbb Z^3$ is not a vector space.

Comment: Perhaps instead of *subspace* you want *subgroup* or *submodule*?

Comment: As OP has now indicated that submodules are the issue, I've added the "commutative-algebra" tag.

Answer (score 1):

It's not true that *the* generating set for $N$ is $\{(1,1,1),~(3,-2,0)\}$, but it is true that *a* generating set for $N$ is $\{(1,1,1),~(3,-2,0)\}$. There are many generating sets for any two-dimensional subspace. Another example for this space would be $\{(1,1,1),~(4,-1,1)\}$.

We can see this as follows: For any integers $x$ and $y$, we know that $z=\frac{2}{5}x+\frac{3}{5}y$ is an integer if and only if $(x,y,z)$ is in $N$.

Consider $(x,y,z)\in N$, then notice that $(z,z,z) + (\frac{3}{5}x-\frac{3}{5}y,~ -\frac{2}{5}x+\frac{2}{5}y,~ 0)=(x,y,z)$, which can be rewritten as $(1,1,1)(z)+(3,-2,0)(\frac{x-y}{5})$. So we're almost good. You need to be a little careful here because it's not entirely clear that $\frac{x-y}{5}$ is an integer.

Comment: I am sorry, Ofcourse I wanted to ask if it is a generating set

Comment: If $2x+3y-5z=0$, then $5$ divides $2x+3y$, so $5$ divides $2x-2y$, so $5$ divides $x-y$.